# Simple harmonic motion question about amplitude

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on a question which describes that there is a particle $P$ of mass 0.6kg (which is not so relevant) attached to an elastic spring of natural length 2.5m. The other end of the spring is attached to a fixed point $A$ on the smooth horizontal plane on which $P$ lies. The particle is held at point $B$ where AB=4m and released from rest. The motion of the particle can be described using the equation    $x''=-\frac{50}{3}x$  where $x$m is the displacement of $P $ from $A$. The question asks for the amplitude and period of the subsequent motion. How can the simple harmonic  motion be taking place about centre $A$ and not the point 2.5m away from $A$ of the  natural length of the spring especially since the amplitude is given as 1.5m in the answers?

Comment: I think that the equation is $x''=-50x/3$ and not yours.

Comment: Yes sorry I edited it but the question still stands

Comment: Looks like a simple typo in the question to me. This is not unheard of.